# Why isn't the JSON object an array?

Tags: c++, json, arrays

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"strings": {
    "keyone": "abc",
    "keytwo": "def",
    }
}
```

Using C++,

```
const Json::Value strings = root["strings"];
for (int index = 0; index < strings.size(); index++) 
{
    std::cout << strings.isArray() << std::endl;
    std::cout << strings.get(index, "ERROR") << std::endl;
}
```

`strings.IsArray()` returns 0, saying it's not an array. And the second line `strings.get(index, "ERROR)"`, just crashes when executing, probably because I'm using it like an array when it's not.

So I'm assuming strings is just a string and not an array. How can I make it an array object?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Why **doesn't** the JSON above contain a JSON-Array? JSON types (Array, Object, String, etc) are all distinct and do not "share" an ancestor (unlike JavaScript Arrays and JavaScript Objects). Most implementations tend to thus *not* allow a JSON-Object to be treated as a JSON-Array (and doing so would actually violate the JSON guarantees of such structures).

Comment: @AndréCaron I am using JsonCpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "strings.IsArray()" returns 0, saying it's not an array

Of course it does, `"strings":{ ... }` is an "object" in JSON terms.